# Mail Attachment in php

Tags: php, phpmailer

In my code mail function working here is fine but the attachment shows only as a name but i want an attachment to be a download type.

Here is the code:

```
<?php 
 include("db.php");
 if(isset($_POST['submit']))
 {
    $cname=$_POST['cname'];
    $file = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    if($file != "")
    {
     $secondname=rand(0,10000000000);
     $uploaddir = "img/careers/";
     $upload_pic = $uploaddir.$secondname.$file;
     copy($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $upload_pic);
     chmod("$uploaddir",0777); 
   } 

$email='nishanth.radical@gmail.com'; 
$subject ="Acknowledgement"; 
$from='developer@sixthstar.in'; 
$message ="Dear $cname,

Test Mail your resume is $upload_pic";

$headers = "From:".$from;

@mail($email,$subject,$message,$headers); 

//echo "<div style='width: 350px; text-align: center; margin: 20% auto 0px; font-family: arial; font-size: 14px; border: 1px solid #ddd; padding: 20px 
//   40px;'> Please wait while we update the record loading...</div>";
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.location = 'careers.php?msg=1'</script>";
exit();

 }  
?>
```

This is my form code:

```
 <form method="post" action="" id="accountx" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
    <div class="form-body pl-0">
      <div class="spacer-b30">
        <div class="tagline">
           <span>Apply for a Job </span>
        </div>
  <!-- .tagline -->
      </div>
      <div class="section">
        <label class="field prepend-icon">
           <input type="text" name="cname" id="cname" class="gui-input" placeholder="Name...">
           <span class="field-icon">
             <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
           </span>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="section">
      <label class="field prepend-icon">
          <input type="file" name="file" id="file" class="gui-input" placeholder="Upload Resume">
           <span class="field-icon">
                    <i class="fa fa-file"></i>
           </span>
        </label>
     </div> 
</form>
```

All the mail functions are working good but i want an attachment to be download format.

Comment: your not attaching a file to the email .. suggest not using mail() but use phpmailer instead.

Comment: anyother way to overwrite above code to add attachment

Answer (score 0):

So,
You can use phpmailer library
https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

`

```
$email = new PHPMailer();
$email->From      = 'from@abcd.com';
$email->FromName  = 'from name';
$email->Subject   = 'Subject';
$email->Body      = 'Body';
$email->AddAddress( 'to@someperson.com' );
$email->AddAttachment( "/path/to/file" , "filename.ext", 'base64', 'application/octet-stream' );
$email->Send();
```

`

Comment: what? thats not a valid use of mail https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Answer (score 0):

This code I found after a long search, **But my suggestion is to us the phpmailer**.

The mail() function doesn’t support attachment or HTML mail by default. You need to use different headers and MIME mail parts to make this possible. Many shared hosting providers doesn’t allow the usage of this function and it might be disabled.

Normally you will pass three values to the mail() function plus some headers. In the example below I skip the value for the message value, because the message is defined as a MIME part together with the attachment. Below is an example on how I use this mail_attachment function to send an email message with one attached .zip file:

```
<?php
function mail_attachment($filename, $path, $mailto, $from_mail, $from_name, $replyto, $subject, $message) {
  $file = $path.$filename;
  $file_size = filesize($file);
  $handle = fopen($file, "r");
  $content = fread($handle, $file_size);
  fclose($handle);
  $content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));
  $uid = md5(uniqid(time()));
  $header = "From: ".$from_name." <".$from_mail.">\r\n";
  $header .= "Reply-To: ".$replyto."\r\n";
  $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
  $header .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$uid."\"\r\n\r\n";
  $header .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\r\n";
  $header .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
  $header .= "Content-type:text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
  $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n";
  $header .= $message."\r\n\r\n";
  $header .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
  $header .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".$filename."\"\r\n"; // use different content types here
  $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
  $header .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$filename."\"\r\n\r\n";
  $header .= $content."\r\n\r\n";
  $header .= "--".$uid."--";
  if (mail($mailto, $subject, "", $header)) {
   echo "mail send ... SUCCESS";
  } else {
   echo "mail send ... ERROR!";
  }
}

$my_file = "somefile.zip";
$my_path = "/your_path/to_the_attachment/";
$my_name = "Olaf Lederer";
$my_mail = "my@mail.com";
$my_replyto = "my_reply_to@mail.net";
$my_subject = "This is a mail with attachment.";
$my_message = "Hallo,rndo you like this script? I hope it will help.rnrngr. Olaf";
mail_attachment($my_file, $my_path, "recipient@mail.org", $my_mail, $my_name, $my_replyto, $my_subject, $my_message);
```

I have tested this and this too working!